# Is the iPhone X still waterproof if the glass over the camera is damaged?

Tags: iphone, camera

Unfortunately I damaged the glass over the camera on my iPhone X

[image]

I wonder if it still is waterproof now?

Comment: I've edited the question to focus on one issue only.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The camera glass is an important part of the barrier that keeps water out of the iPhone. I would have it repaired soon if you can’t keep it scrupulously dry.

The physics of water meeting a small crack mean if you set this phone down on a wet surface, a large amount of water could wick into the case via [capillary action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capillary_action).